# Yarn workspace, react, monorepo issue with conflict library version

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, yarnpkg, monorepo, yarn-workspaces

I'm experimenting with yarn workspace monorepo. It is consisting of a TestProject created with `create-react-app`, and a SharedLib1 which is created with `create-react-library`. TestProject imports code from SharedLib1. The problem being, TestProject uses react-scripts 3.3.0 which is dependent on babel-jest ^24.9.0, while SharedLib1 uses react-scripts-ts ^2.16.0 which is dependent on babel-jest 22.4.4. When running `yarn start` in TestProject, it complains:

```
The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:

  "babel-jest": "^24.9.0"

Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it automatically.
However, a different version of babel-jest was detected higher up in the tree:

  /monoRepo/node_modules/babel-jest (version: 22.4.4)
```

I could disable the error by setting `SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true` in TestProject or manually upgrade the react-scripts inside SharedLib1, but I'd like to know if there's a better way of handling this.

```
myMonorepo
 -web
   -SharedLib1
     -package.json
   -TestProject
     -package.json
 -package.json
```

Package.json of myMonoRepo:

```
{
  "name": "my-mono-repo",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "workspaces": [
    "web/*"
  ],
  "nohoist": [
    "**/babel-jest",
    "**/babel-jest/**"
  ]
}
```

Package.json of myMonoRepo:

```
{
  "name": "test-proj",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "shared-lib-1": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

And the test code App.tsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import TestComp from 'shared-lib-1';

import './App.css';

const App: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TestComp text={'aaa'}/>
      Learn React
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

There is a babel-jest 24.9.0 inside the node_modules of TestProj and another 22.4.4 inside the node_modules of myMonoRepo

Comment: Can you share what locations you find `babel-jest` at on your filesystem in your multiple `node_modules` folders? Also can you share the output of `yarn why babel-jest`?

Comment: Could you publish a sample minimal project to a public repository?

Answer (score 1):

This is very similar, if not the same, to an issue opened on [the GH repo for create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6305#issuecomment-459993495) and you may find additional information there.

That said, you might try moving `babel-jest` to a `devDependency` instead of a package dependency. If that does not work, you might try [Selective dependency resolutions](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/#toc-how-to-use-it), where you can force your project to a specific version of `babel-jest` -

```js
"resolutions": {
   "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
   "shared-lib-1": "^1.0.0"
}
```